# Single page fixed viewport

Tags: html, css

I am currently making a single page scrolling vertical site which has the viewport locked at 100% height.

The problem I have is that the designs that were given to me were calculated for a 1200x800 (macbook 13") view but I am using 1920x1080 (macmini) resolution.

Furthermore, the usable height area in each screen is limited by each widget that the browser uses so the 800 might actually be for example 638 height (it is more profound in the ipads where 768 browser height in total is not 768 at all). Also, the design must be centered in width and height. For **width**, I can use `margin:0 auto`, but height is trickier because it would need to make a div absolute.

What I did so far was to make a div absolute and have it manipulated by javascript, but I would like to know ***if there is a pure css way to do it*** since javascript would require much cases and excess code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what i'm using with body height and html height at 100%

```
<div style=" display:table;width:100%;height:100%">
    <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it compatible with let's say... IE8 (IE9 at least)?

Comment: http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html says compatibility is IE8+ but i havn't tried it myself in IE my site is a mobile site

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but actually my problem is mostly on height. I got an Illustratior file that is designed for 1200x800, which is the theoretical part, and it's fixed with images and stuff for that resolution. But I would like it to have a similar view on 1920x1080, so that's what I am looking for. Would making it into percentage work?

Comment: yes use percentages, ems etc anything other than px basically